# Flutter: problem with SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations when I use it with an iPad

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, orientation

In my project, I only need to have one page in landscape mode and not in portrait mode, while the rest of the pages are in portrait and landscape mode.

As per the documentation, I used  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations

```
   @override 
   void initState() {
    
    // set the screen in landscape mode
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);

   super.initState();
}
```

and

```
 @override
  void dispose() {
    // restore the
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);
    
    super.dispose();
  }
```

when I exit the page to restore the portrait mode.

Now, while with the iPhone it works perfectly, with the iPad it is as if it were not there and both landscape and portrait are possible.
Of course as I don't want the whole application in landscape mode but only one page I can't act on info.plist.
Has anyone had the same problem?
Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue. ```SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations``` works very unreliably across different devices. so far i havn't found a fix.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The solution there is here:
[flutter IOS landscape](https://www.flutterbeads.com/change-lock-device-orientation-portrait-landscape-flutter/)

Answer (score 1):

in case of iPad please set in info.plist

```
<key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
<true/>
```

after adding this SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([....]) will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In dispose keep only portrait up

```dart
 @override
  void dispose() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
    
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Kaushik Chandru. Perhaps I have not explained myself well. The dispose works as required it is when entering the page that it does not fix on the landscape mode but remains both vertical and horizontal. With iPhone it works fine, with iPad it does not.